# Read Firefox HTML layout engine source code?

Tags: firefox, browser, gecko

I download Firefox latest source code and I want to know the detail of how Firefox layout engine work.
Especially, how block/inline formatting context implemented, how block level and inline level elements layouted.
Can someone give me some advices or links on reading the source code?

update:
I compiled Firefox on Win7 and managed to run it in debug mode and set some breakpoint. But I'm stucked. Where should I put a breakpoint so that I can step through the code which calculate the x,y,w,h of html elements.

[image]

Comment: This might be one of the most ambitious questions I've seen around here.  What do you intend to do with this?  Are you trying to write a browser?

Comment: @durbnpoisn, no, I am not trying to write a browser. I just want to know how Firefox's layout engine works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reading this documents:

- http://www-archive.mozilla.org/newlayout/doc/,
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_Layout_in_Mozilla and
- https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:Home_Page